# Primefaces dynamic Panels and unique ID's

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am having some difficulty in understanding dynamic panel generation in Primefaces and collapsing/closing each panel individually

I have a dynamic # of p:panels being generated inside a ui:repeat which is backed by a List. Adding objects to the list automatically increases my panel count and fields inside the panel render as expected. I am using varStatus=row as a unique index into the panels, however I notice that the panel ID's ARE THE SAME FOR ALL ROWS!!

Trying to force ID by using the row variable does not work but the same row variable is being used in the panel header attribute and panel header is rendered dynamically. this is causing problems when I close or toggle the panel which caused ALL panels ot be closed/toggled because the panel ID for all rows is the same....

How can i dynamically render panels with associated close.toggle functionality?

```
            <p:panel header="#{(app.name == null || app.name.length() == 0) ? 'Application '.concat(row.index+1) : app.name }"  
           toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500"  collapsed="#{app.panelCollapsed}">
```